# Wowza Android sample-app: Write access denied for stream 9x9x9999

Tags: android, wowza-transcoder

I just want to get the Android Gocoder "sample-app" running against the Wowza cloud.

I have downloaded, compiled, and launched the code onto my Android Samsung 5

Now I'm getting this error when I try to stream video from Android to Wowza cloud:

### "Write access denied for stream 9x9x9999 "

Here are the local app settings (some #'s faked for security):

Host addr: 99.999.999.99

Port #: 1935

App Name: [live]

Stream Name [9x9x9999 ]
Source user name & pw (not set)

and here's the LiveStream config'n on the wowza website:

Source Connection Information

Primary Server  rtmp://x9x9x9.entrypoint.cloud.wowza.com/app-b553 (99.999.999.99 )
Host Port   1935
Stream Name 9x9x9999 
Disable Authentication  Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I got back an answer from Wowza that worked:

The application name that you are using looks to be incorrect. It should be **app-b553**. In Wowza Streaming Cloud, the primary server URL is usually in the following format:

rtmp://[host-address]/[app-name]

(also, make sure you use "other RTMP" and not "Wowza Gocoder" for "Video Source and Transcoder")